# mySQL connection issue when migrating from webserver to MAMP

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

OK so I've recently moved to MAMP for a project using PHP and mySQL. I've set up the database and copied all the data but now the script doesn't work. I haven't changed the default username or password. Any ideas? Here's the code I'm using, it fails at connecting to the database.

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "test";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "root";

mysql_connect("$dbhost", "$dbuser", "$dbpass") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("$dbname") or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: It fails with what error message?

Comment: 'Error connection to mysql', the one PHP tells it to throw out. It's styled in the CSS for the page too if that's of any use.

Comment: change the 'Error connecting to mysql' string to `mysql_error()` instead. No point in just saying something blew up. At least have the attempt spit out the one and only bit of information that would be useful: The actual error message.

Comment: changed that and it gives the same result...

Comment: Please update your question with the new error handling and report the *actual* message you get. Those are usually sth like an error code `HYxxxx` in that message...

Comment: I've updated the code but as I said, I'm not receiving a new error message.

Comment: Are you 100% sure this is a database issue in the first place?

Comment: The PHP should be fine as it worked in my web based version, as far as I know the default username and password are both 'root' and I've got a database called 'text' (but the script doesn't even get this far). Am I missing something?

Comment: is the database server running?

Comment: What does a `show grants for root@localhost` show? Same password hash as on the old system? Anything in the web server's own error log?

Comment: Oh, and connecting to any database using the superuser account from a webserver is bad form - even if it's just for private development. Always use a limited-privilege account for such things. It's trivial to create one and a VERY good habit to get into

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check what value php.ini has for the default mysql socket - MAMP creates one in /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql whereas the mysql default location is /tmp

Comment: I changed the line mysql.default_socket = /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock to mysql.default_socket = /tmp but still no difference. Could my default mySQL not be running?

Comment: By default there is no MySQL on OSX. If you want to use the MAMP supplied MySQL server you should leave it as it was. The problem comes when the built-in PHP tries to access the Database.

To get around the confusion, pick which MySQL you want to use (either MAMPs or a normal install from MySQL.com) and then symlink the socket file from the other location to the actual socket

Comment: I want to use MAMP's mySQL, but I thought OS X came with one pre-installed so I was wary that the two might be conflicting. I'm unfamiliar with sockets - how would I go about symlinking the two files?

Comment: I've copied the socket file to /Applications/MAMP/tmp/ but I get the error "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql.sock' (38)"

Comment: Also, it might be relevant that I had to change the port of the mySQL server from 8889 to 3306 to get it working.

Comment: You can't copy a socket file - they don't work like that.

If you want to use MAMP's MySQL server, make sure your php.ini points to /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql.sock

If you had to change the port, it sounds like you were connecting to 127.0.0.1 not localhost - one makes a TCP/IP connection, the other makes a socket based connection.